# how to separate the grade of the student

Tags: php, html

kindly help me, i'm on the making of online student information and it have many students and i don't know how to separate the grades of the student according to their *StudID* (student ID).

My code goes like this...

```
function Content() 
{
      $code = <<< htmlcode
        <center>
            <form name="frmGrade" method="POST" action="" style="padding-top:30px;">
                <table border="1" align="center">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center">Subject</td>
                    <td align="center">First Grading</td>
                    <td align="center">Second Grading</td>
                    <td align="center">Third Grading</td>
                    <td align="center">Fourth Grading</td>
                    <td align="center">Average</td>
                    <td align="center">Remarks</td>
                  </tr>
        </center>
        htmlcode;

    //-------------------------------------
    // retrieve data from database
    //-------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT Subject,FirstGrading,SecondGrading,ThirdGrading,FourthGrading,Average,Remarks FROM grades WHERE StudID = '002' ;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //-------------------------------------
    // fetch each record from database
    //-------------------------------------
    if($num_rows > 0)
    {

        for($ctr = 1; $ctr <= $num_rows; $ctr++)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $sub = $row['Subject'];
            $fg = $row['FirstGrading'];
            $secg = $row['SecondGrading'];
            $thg = $row['ThirdGrading'];
            $fourthg = $row['FourthGrading'];
            $ave = $row['Average'];
            $remarks = $row['Remarks'];

            $code .= <<< htmlcode
                <tr $bg>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $sub </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $fg </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $secg </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $thg  </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $fourthg </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $ave </td>
                    <td style="padding:5;"> $remarks </td>
                    $actions
                </tr>
            htmlcode;
        }

        //-------------------------------------
        // end table 
        //-------------------------------------
        $code .= "</table> </form></center> </br></br>";

    }

    //-------------------------------------
    // Display table
    //-------------------------------------

    return $code;
}
?>
```

what i want is that when Student one with StudID=001 he/she will see are the grade of him/her and when student two with StudID=002 will see ONLY his grade.

Comment: Is this a PHP+HTML question or a SQL question?

Comment: Do you already have a login/user system which lets you know which student is viewing? If so, you only need to update your `SELECT` statement

Comment: **NOTE:** The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used for new projects. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO prepared statements instead. Besides that, if you ask a question on SO, you need to have a basic understanding of the problem, which you don't seem to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch row from `$result` in `while loop` not `for loop`

```
function Content($sid) 
{
  $code = <<< htmlcode
    <center>
        <form name="frmGrade" method="POST" action="" style="padding-top:30px;">
            <table border="1" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">Subject</td>
                <td align="center">First Grading</td>
                <td align="center">Second Grading</td>
                <td align="center">Third Grading</td>
                <td align="center">Fourth Grading</td>
                <td align="center">Average</td>
                <td align="center">Remarks</td>
              </tr>
    </center>
    htmlcode;

//-------------------------------------
// retrieve data from database
//-------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT Subject,FirstGrading,SecondGrading,ThirdGrading,FourthGrading,Average,Remarks FROM grades WHERE StudID = '$sid' ;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

//-------------------------------------
// fetch each record from database
//-------------------------------------
if($num_rows > 0)
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $sub = $row['Subject'];
        $fg = $row['FirstGrading'];
        $secg = $row['SecondGrading'];
        $thg = $row['ThirdGrading'];
        $fourthg = $row['FourthGrading'];
        $ave = $row['Average'];
        $remarks = $row['Remarks'];

        $code .= <<< htmlcode
            <tr $bg>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $sub </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $fg </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $secg </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $thg  </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $fourthg </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $ave </td>
                <td style="padding:5;"> $remarks </td>
                $actions
            </tr>
        htmlcode;
    }

    //-------------------------------------
    // end table 
    //-------------------------------------
    $code .= "</table> </form></center> </br></br>";

}

//-------------------------------------
// Display table
//-------------------------------------

return $code;
}
?>

<?php
    //to get content for student 001
    echo Content('001');

    //to get content for student 002
    echo Content('002');
?>
```

Comment: What does this answer?

Comment: He should get content for StudId='002', There was a mistake to fetch row.

Comment: @kingkero: is any mistake from me?

Comment: I only disliked that the only thing you posted was a bunch of code with no explanation whatsoever

Comment: You are right but there was a brief explanation in one line because there is only one for loop which is replaced by while. However I will try better next. Thanks.

Comment: @salim but now its having a two header and its not distributing the grades its only posting the grades of student 1